# Typo in the "Public Network Terms of Service"

Tags: bug, legal, spelling, terms-of-service

In the [Public Network Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/) page, there is a typo. In the second point, the character "e" is missing from word "Enforceable".

[image: Second point typo]

> 2. Contracts are Binding and Legally Enforcable – Please Read!

this should be

> 2. Contracts are Binding and Legally Enforc**e**able – Please Read!

It is handled correctly in the [Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/#contracts) section.

[image: Contract]

Comment: Remember! Contracts are binding, but you can legally stick a forc  in them.

Comment: Or perhaps the really are supposed to be enforkable, eaten with gusto and relish...

Comment: thanks for letting us know, we'll note it down to be fixed in a future update.